# Office JS Outlook and update email body when composing a form

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I would like to know if with Office JS Outlook addin, is it possible to set email body automatically when opening and composing an email.

I have already succeed to do it using addin commands and MessageComposeCommandSurface extension point element in the manifest.

However, my code is execution only after a click on a button in the ribbon.

Is it possible to execute my code automatically when the compose form is loading instead of having to click in a button to execute it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Outlook web addin does not support automation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a supported scenario.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19219975)

Comment: @zx485 I disagree, I think that it's an answer - the OP was asking if something is possible, and his answer is claiming that it's not. I don't know offhand if it's true, but that has no bearing on whether it's an answer or not - "no, it's not possible" is actually an answer here.